# messbar sein/ etwas messbar machen

Tags: meaning

> ***messen*** - sich messen lassend

Quelle: Duden

Diese Sätze ergeben für mich wenig Sinn, insbesondere der zweite

> So machst du deine Ziele messbar.
>
> Aber wie lässt sich Nachhaltigkeit steuern und messbar machen?

Was heißt eigentlich "etwas messbar" machen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etwas zu messen, bedeutet, dass der Größe, die gemessen werden soll, ein ganz konkreter Zahlenwert zugeordnet wird. Diese Zuordnung muss bestimmte Kriterien erfüllen:

- wenn sich die Größe verdoppelt, sollte sich die zugeordnete Zahl ebenfalls verdoppeln
- Wenn unterschiedliche Leute dieselbe Größe mit demselben Maßstab (also mit derselben Methode) messen, sollen sie denselben Zahlenwert erhalten.

»Nachhaltigkeit« ist aber ein Beispiel für eine Größe, die von sich aus diese Bedingungen nicht erfüllt. Es liegt nicht a priori auf der Hand, wie sich der Nachhaltigkeit z.B. einer bestimmten Herstellungsmethode von Herrenhemden, ein ganz konkreter Zahlenwert zuordnen lässt. Auch ist nicht ohne weiteres einsichtig, was hier mit »Verdoppeln der Nachhaltigkeit« gemeint sein könnte.

Man muss also eine Methode finden, um diese Hindernisse zu umgehen. Es müssen Definitionen gefunden werden, und es müssen auch Methoden ausgearbeitet werden. All diese Maßnahmen zusammen machen es dann im Erfolgsfall möglich, der Nachhaltigkeit von Herstellungsmethoden auf eindeutige und nachvollziehbare Weisen, einen Zahlenwert zuzuordnen.

Genau das ist mit »Nachhaltigkeit messbar machen« gemeint.

Wenn Nachhaltigkeit gemessen werden kann, kann man die Nachhaltigkeit verschiedener Methoden miteinander vergleichen. Das ist entweder unmöglich, oder nur sehr viel schwer möglich, wenn die Nachhaltigkeit nicht messbar gemacht wird.

Comment: Ein linearer Zusammenhang zwischen Maßzahl und Größe (dein erstes Postulat) ist nicht notwendig, um etwas zu messen - Siehe z.B. das gängige Maß der Lautstärke oder das Maß einer Verstärkung in der Elektronik, also alles, was in dB gemessen wird.

Comment: @Tofro: Das Bel, das davon abgeleitete Dezibel und das Neper sind logarithmische Maße. Das, wovon der Logarithmus genommen wird, erfüllt in allen Fällen die von mir beschriebene Anforderung.

Comment: Nein, tut es nicht. Doppelt so laut sind nicht doppelt soviel dB. Das sind logarithmische Zusammenhänge.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn etwas doppelt so laut ist (**mal** 2), nimmt der Lautstärkepegel um 1 Bel (= 10 Dezibel) zu (**plus** 1). Das ist ein logarithmischer Zusammenhang. Die Lautstärke selbst (Schalldruck oder Schallschnelle), also das, was tatsächlich gemessen wird, und wovon dann der Logarithmus genommen wird, verdoppelt sich aber sehr wohl (**mal** 2). Genau aus diesem Grund nennt man die Einheiten Bel, Dezibel und viele andere auch [Hilfsmaßeinheiten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilfsmaßeinheit#Logarithmisch) oder Pseudomaße, weil es eben keine echten Maßeinheiten sind.